# Subversion merge disappeared after power failure

Tags: svn, merge

After a power failure, a branch that I had deleted (after merging it back into the trunk) reappeared, and all the commits since that merge disappeared.  I used the CLI and the following commands to perform the merge:

```
$ svn co https://domain/repos/svn/proj/trunk
$ cd trunk/
$ svn merge --reintegrate https://domain/repos/svn/proj/branches/03-12
$ svn commit -m "Merge 03-12 branch back into trunk"
```

Am running subversion-1.6.11-10, and am concerned that I missed a step.  I've never seen subversion problems after an outage before.

Comment: Do you mean that you lost some last revisions? What is `svnadmin verify` saying?

Comment: Yes to the lost last revisions.  The last ~50 revisions I've checked in are no longer showing up in the trunk I checked out ~10 days ago.  Also, the completed merge is not in the repo.  Strangely, I had deleted the branch after the merge, and now the branch is back.

Thanks for mentioning "svnadmin verify".  That command shows the last revision as 1336.  In the branch I made, before it was merged, the last revision was 1335.

I checked out the trunk right after the merge, and a file that has not been modified since that checkout since then shows revision 1337.  My desktop shows revision 1382.

Comment: Your question got me looking at the nightly backups, which show a 1382 also.  But, rather than that revision being in a path like .../svn/db/revs/1/*, it's in a new directory .../svn.aftermerge1/db/revs/1/* (svn.aftermerge1 was probably a directory I created during the merge process).  Note that the svn repo is mounted on the HTTP server via NFS, and it has mounted svn only, not svn.aftermerge1.  So, this indicates something about why my svn client no longer sees the last ~50 (HTTP SVN server does not see svn.aftermerge1).  Am confused 1) why a new path, and 2) what I did wrong...